# Should I use Entity Framework navigation properties for querying rather than straight from the DataContext ICollections?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to get my head around creating projections in Entity Framework 6 and mapping these projections to my view models. My concerns are the number of database connections and separate queries that are sent when using navigation properties. For example:

(my root)

```
var item = db.CourseContainers.First(p => p.ID == id); 
item
   .CourseItems
   .SelectMany(p => p.CourseItemLessons)
   .Select(p => new LessonsListItem() {
      ID = p.CourseItemID,
      Name = p.Lesson.Name
   }).ToList()
```

I am pulling all courseitems with courseitemlessons and then projecting to a viewmodel also using the Lesson navigation to get the name. I don't think I am understanding how the entity framework is parsing this. I would expect something like:

```
SELECT [cil].ID,
       [l].Name
FROM   CourseItems ci INNER JOIN
       CourseItemLessons cil ON ci.ID = cil.CourseItemID INNER JOIN
       Lessons l ON cil.LessonID = l.ID
WHERE  ci.CourseID = @courseID
```

I have just written this out as expected. I know the table structure is a bit odd. Instead of above, there are multiple connections and select statements, this is what is actually sent to the db.

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Extent1].[DateModified] AS [DateModified], 
    [Extent1].[AddedBy] AS [AddedBy], 
    [Extent1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[IsLinear] AS [IsLinear], 
    [Extent1].[Privacy] AS [Privacy]
    FROM [dbo].[CourseContainers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0


-- p__linq__0: '7' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

Opened connection at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Extent1].[DateModified] AS [DateModified], 
    [Extent1].[AddedBy] AS [AddedBy], 
    [Extent1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded], 
    [Extent1].[SortOrder] AS [SortOrder], 
    [Extent1].[CourseID] AS [CourseID]
    FROM [dbo].[CourseItems] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CourseID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '7' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

Opened connection at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Extent1].[DateModified] AS [DateModified], 
    [Extent1].[AddedBy] AS [AddedBy], 
    [Extent1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded], 
    [Extent1].[CourseItemID] AS [CourseItemID], 
    [Extent1].[ObjectID] AS [ObjectID]
    FROM [dbo].[CourseItemLessons] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CourseItemID] = @EntityKeyValue1


-- EntityKeyValue1: '1049' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

Opened connection at 26/03/2015 12:01:44 PM +10:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Extent1].[DateModified] AS [DateModified], 
    [Extent1].[AddedBy] AS [AddedBy], 
    [Extent1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Privacy] AS [Privacy]
    FROM [dbo].[Lessons] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

This will continue for however many lessons/courseitems there are.

I think this is because *item* is in memory already but I am not sure. If I change my code to this:

```
Lessons = (from ci in db.CourseItems
           join cil in db.CourseItemLessons on ci.ID equals cil.CourseItemID
           join l in db.Lessons on cil.ObjectID equals l.ID
           where ci.CourseID == item.ID
           select new { ID = ci.ID, Name = l.Name }).ToList()
           .Select(p => new LessonsListItem() { ID = p.ID, Name = p.Name}).ToList()
```

I end up with my expected result:

```
Opened connection at 26/03/2015 12:06:43 PM +10:00

SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM   [dbo].[CourseItems] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CourseItemLessons] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[CourseItemID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Lessons] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ObjectID] = [Extent3].[ID]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CourseID] = @p__linq__0


-- p__linq__0: '7' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- Executing at 26/03/2015 12:06:43 PM +10:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

I know I can just use this, but I mean, what is the use of using navigation properties if they are going to query every row individually as a select with a where clause?

Comment: Steve, nice analysis and question.  Here's a tip for you based on my tinkering with EF.  If you find that the SQL generated by EF is not to your liking you may always override it and issue the query directly to the database using the db.database.SQLQUERY<T>() method.  The T parameter tells the SQL engine what type to return so you actually get the best of both worlds... Finely tuned queries you design, and strongly typed returns.  I'm working on a project now where they said they got rid of all EF stuff because it was too slow.  I thought hmmmm.... Really?

Comment: Thanks John, I appreciate the reply. I didn't know that it would map directly back to an object using SqlQuery. That's a plus in opposed to just straight ADO and then mapping it myself. I'll have to rethink my approach.

Comment: No problem Steve.  I was working on a project last year where the DBs had locked down the database I was working with.  EF worked on reads but not on Saves...  That's when I started hunting for a solution within EF and found that method.  The project was a success because of strong type returns that made binding easy.  Fast forward, just recently I've been learning how to deserialize JSON data into strong types... I'm just a strong type bigot.

Comment: using the navigational properties helps to save writing multiple queries. For example, if you only had a very basic method that return a single CourseContainer object. It alone can satisfy the needs of other methods, such as a method that counts the number of courseitems, or a method like yours that projects the results to a lessionlistitem

Comment: @failedprogramming I am not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: I was pointing out the benefits of lazy loading, but after reading your question again, i think i may have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the First() IS the projection. If I pull out that First() and add the query as a where then the IQueryable solves correctly.

```
var items = db.CourseContainers
   .Where(p => p.ID == id)
   .SelectMany(p => p.CourseItems)
   .SelectMany(p => p.CourseItemLessons)
   .Select(p => new LessonsListItem() {
      ID = p.CourseItemID,
      Name = p.Lesson.Name
   }).ToList()
```

The following has more information on the issue.
[Should I use Entity Framework navigation properties for querying rather than straight from the DataContext ICollections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269926)